# android send data to device?

Tags: android, xamarin, server, xamarin.android, client

we have an application under xamarin where a user connected and on a login the user DOWNLOAD the work he make it.
Device call our web service and device downloaded the datas in json format.
The data downloaded are saved into the database sql lite on client.
All work fine.

Now imagine this sample : 
user has connected on the device, downloaded work.
But afer some hours,  the work has changed for some reason.
We need to send new data (new work) again the particular device.

I've read some article about the google push notification but i wonder if i search on the right place.

How i can send data to a particular device under android ?
Could you share your experience, article , sample..

Thanks for your knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've read some article about the google push notification but i wonder if i search on the right place.

There is a [realtime database on Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/?authuser=0) that will fit your requirement. But it is a cloud based service, using it probably means you  have to move all your data from your server to Firebase server. So it is not a good fit, if you want to use your own webservice.

Other option is to use an [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to set a repeating task to sync your data periodically.

Comment: Hello elvis xia, thanks for your informations ...right i think firebase will be the right solution just send a push to the device when the device receive this notification => call our HttpRequest i think it will be our solution PREFER than have an alarm manager who check every 15 min or any time => we don't know witch user the work changed ... thanks for all our knowledge guy great to find any suggestion or help here everyday :)